# Default / standard ReST web service path / method

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I was wondering **if there is a default path / method for ReST services**? There is probably no defined standard method but is there something like a de facto standard?

Usage scenarios for that would be for testing availability, connectability, correct authentication etc. So if that "default dummy" method works one knows that everything regarding the connection works.

I googled around a bit but nothing seems to jump out. Possible canditates for me would be:

- /version (returns the version of the ReST service)
- /whoami (returns the user name)
- /alive (returns true or false)
- ...

Any other methods I missed?

Comment: `/ping` must return `pong`.

Comment: Funny, that one also crossed my mind :-)

Comment: And `ping/pong` is used by real systems (XMPP: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html). So no kidding :)